# Python Gmail API won't pass labelIds Parameter to List method

Tags: python, gmail, gmail-api

I've been trying to get a Python script set up that involves querying a Gmail account for unread messages. Ideally I'd like to make use of the Gmail API's "list" method with the optional query parameter filtering for messages with the labelId of "UNREAD".

When I test this out on Google's site (https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list) , it works properly.

But within my script, the labelId parameter seems to not be passed correctly and my output is always the full list of messages.

Here's the line of code I've got right now:

```
results = service.users().messages().list(userId='me', labelIds='UNREAD').execute()
```

This returns all messages in the inbox, not filtered to UNREAD only.

I've come across some documentation on people having a similar issue with the optional queries ('q' parameter in the Gmail API list method) but not for labelIds.

Does anyone have any experience with this problem?

Answer (score 1):

How about this modification? I think that there are several patterns for your situation.

#### Pattern 1:

```
results = service.users().messages().list(userId='me', labelIds=['UNREAD']).execute()
```

For example, if you want to retrieve the unread messages in the inbox, you can use `userId='me', labelIds=['UNREAD', 'INBOX']` and `userId='me', labelIds=['UNREAD'], q='in:inbox'`.

#### Pattern 2:

```
results = service.users().messages().list(userId='me', q='is:unread').execute()
```

For example, if you want to retrieve the unread messages in the inbox, you can use `userId='me', q='in:inbox is:unread'`.

#### References:

- [Users.messages: list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list)
- [Search operators you can use with Gmail](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en)

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but neither of those solved my problem. The id's of all messages in the inbox are still returned rather than just unread. I did some more digging and it seems similar to the issue described here: https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/issues/469                         but i'm not sure how their workaround with 'qs' can be applied.

Comment: @JEK I'm really sorry for the inconvenience. In my environment, I could confirm that those patterns worked. So I worry about my environment might be different from yours. For example, in order to retrieve the messages in the inbox, when ``service.users().messages().list(userId='me', labelIds=['INBOX']).execute()`` and ``service.users().messages().list(userId='me', q='in:inbox').execute()`` are used, what values will you get? In my environment, the messages in the inbox can be retrieved from both samples.